# Gimp batch create from differing elements

Tags: batch-file, gimp

I am trying to create images made up from different elements, some of which are static, some of which are variable.

The endresult should be a set of flyers, made of of a background image, a logo (both static) as well as a QR code and a description of the QR code (text) - both variable.

I do have the background image, logo and QR codes (several dozens) as separate files and am looking for a away to batch create these flyers automatically whereby each QR code is combined wit the background image and the logo (and ideally text as well).

I am well versed with BIMP, however this doesn't allow the option to have certain elements be variables.

Comment: I guess this is none of the few questions where tag [tag:batch-file] has erroneously been selected although [tag:batch-processing] was actually meant -- please read the related tag infos and update your question accordingly...

Comment: "The endresult should be a set of flyers" -> you do not want to use an image-manipulation program to do this. The background, the logo - yes, though logos can benefit from being done in a vector graphics application. The QR code? Created as an image asset by e.g. the barcode utility. The description? Word processor. The compositing into a flyer: an application geared towards that task - and one which lets you keep the asstes mentioned up to now external, so that you can change them on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget Gimp and use ImageMagick's `compose` utility.

See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/).